# how i+=i works in a foor loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

i wanted a for loop that sums a number 'i' with all previous numbers, for example :
if i=5 then i want the loop to calculate the sum (5+4+3+2+1+0), then i tested this code which has returned some strange numbers:

```js
//-----------i<5
for(i=0 ; i<5; i++){
  i += i;
}
console.log(i += i)

//---------i<6
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
  i += i;
}
console.log(i += i)
```

it had returned the **same** value for **different** 'i':

```
//for i <5
14
//for i < 6
14
```

Comment: [Illustrated run of both loops](https://jsbin.com/gigesuruhe/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 3):

That's because they both stop when `i` reaches value of 7. Let's go over every single iteration, shall we?

During first iteration of the loop you:

- start with `i=0`, then you add two zeros together with `i+=i`, and finally increase it by 1 via `i++`, you end up with `i=1`

During second iteration of the loop you:

- start with `i=1`, they you add two 1s together with `i+=i`, and finally increase it by 1 via `i++`,  you end up with `i=3`

During final iteration of the loop you:

- start with `i=3`, they you add two 3s together with `i+=i`, and finally increase it by 1 via `i++`,  you end up with `i=7`

Finally the `console.log(i+=i)` adds two 7s together and you get 14.

Both loops stop at the 3rd iteration when i reaches the value of 7

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are increasing `i` two times in a loop. One with `i++` and second with `i += i`(meaning doubling `i`)

Now lets see how `i` changes in each iteration

```
i = 0;
//First iteration
i = 0(i += i)
i = 1(i++)
//Second iteration
i = 2(i += i)
i = 3(i++)
//Third
i = 6(i += i)
i++ (i = 7)
```

So the loop will exit because 7 > 5. So the last of `i` `7` in both the cases so it gives same value for both loops

**Note:** Don't ever assign variables to values like that. Always use keywords `let`(if you wanna change the variable afterwards). `const`(if you don't want to change variable afterwards). Also try to avoid `var`